# HKLM keys 64 and 32 bits shown a different UBR

Tags: windows

After OS updated from Win2019 10.0.17763.4492 (1809) to Win2019 10.0.17763.4499 (1809), the UBR value under
HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion is not upgraded as in HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion, they are different.

On a PS shell:

Get-ItemProperty 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion' | select UBR

4492

Get-ItemProperty 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion' | select UBR

4499

Reboot done.
How is this possible?